# Unknown command: protocol when using Chromeless on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless, chromeless

Could someone help me with this, I'm running an AWS Lambda using Chromeless and Serverless, I keep getting the same error.

My code:

```
import Chromeless from 'chromeless'

export default async () => {
  const chromeless = new Chromeless({
    remote: {
      endpointUrl: 'https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging',
      apiKey: 'xxx'
    },
  })

  const screenshot = await chromeless
    .goto('https://www.google.com')
    .type('chromeless', 'input[name="q"]')
    .screenshot()

  console.log(screenshot)

  await chromeless.end()
}
```

The error:

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Unknown command: protocol
```

I cant find anything online that could help, so I ran this code as a test and it still fails, it seems to fail as soon as I try and pass anything into screenshot, it doesn't work with `.evaluate()` or `.html()` either. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated I can provide any other files needed!

Comment: Always wrap your `await`-ed calls with a `try...catch`. While this alone will not fix your problem, looking at the error inside the `catch` statement will give you a better idea where it went wrong.